# Store data across tabs/windows but not persist

Tags: javascript, html, http, web, browser

I am looking something to store data in the browser across tabs/windows of my web application, but I do not want it to be persistent (i.e. on disk). If the browser get closed, or machine crashes, the data must be gone. Moreover I would like if the all the tabs/windows of the application get closed, the data are gone as well. It is something like between `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for Service Workers and/or Web Workers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

You would essentially just keep things in memory, shuffling the data between page and service Workers etc

Comment: URL returns 404.

Comment: OK fixed the link.